# Episerver dojo setter on page-editing vs all properties tab

Tags: javascript, dojo, episerver

I've created a simple dojo property that is a simple bullet list, it's possible to add/remove new items.

However I'm having issues getting the setter to work properly in both On page-editing and in the all properties tab.

My setter looks like this:

```
_setValueAttr: function (val) {
    array.forEach(val, this._addRow, this);
}
```

It works fine for the All properties tab because then postCreate has already run and created my container:

```
contentPane: null,

postCreate: function() {
    contentPane = new ContentPane();
}
```

But on the on page-editing tab setValueAttr is being run before postCreate, and then theres no contentPane to attack my rows to..

I found something regarding lifecykles in the documentation, but I'm not sure it's related:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#life-cycle

How can you handle the setter for both views..?

Answer (score 0):

What the best way is depends on the scenario, but as an example you could could try the following in your widget constructor:

```
aspect.after(this, "set", function (name, value) {
   if (name === 'value' && value) {
      // The property value has been set/updated
      // TODO Do something if the content pane has been created
   }
}, true);
```

`aspect` is available by importing `dojo/aspect`.

Comment: Hi Ted, thanks for the reply. I had to shelf the issue for the time being, been busy since. To clarify the matter further: the block is using default values to show On page-editing view first when editing the block. Trying to click on the blue edit area the first function being run is setValueAttr. On the other hand, trancending into the All properties view, my postcreate is being run first. And thus propagating my set via it. I logged the constructor and there seems to not yet be any values to set there, using aspect there "value" is null. Any other ideas?